# CSS: before pseudo elements between <li> with <a> tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm coding for lines which should be divided by "|".
BTW the first element don't need to have separator before.
This code doesn't work for me.

```css
.header-level-1 .clearlist li a:before {
content: "|";}

.header-level-1 .clearlist li a:first-child:before {
   content: ""; 
}
```

```html
<div class="header-level-1">
  <!-- Login -->
  <ul class="clearlist">
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` will always be the first child of `li`.

Try below snippet.

```css
.header-level-1 .clearlist li:not(:first-child)  a::before {
content: "|";}

.header-level-1 .clearlist li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-level-1">
        <!-- Login -->
            <ul class="clearlist">
                <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Check it on fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/6aLocmh9/

:)

Answer (score 2):

the `a` is going to be always the `first-child`/`first-of-type`, you need to select the `li` instead

```css
.clearlist {
  list-style: none;
}


.clearlist li a:before {
  content: "|";
}

.clearlist li:first-of-type a:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="header-level-1">
  <!-- Login -->
  <ul class="clearlist">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

you can also use the `:not()` in the `li`

```css
.clearlist {
  list-style: none;
}

.clearlist li:not(:first-of-type) a:before {
  content: "|";
}
```

```html
<div class="header-level-1">
  <!-- Login -->
  <ul class="clearlist">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header-level-1 .clearlist li{
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    .header-level-1 .clearlist li a:before {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;    
    width:1px;
    height:100%;
    background:black;
    left:-5px;
    }
    
    .header-level-1 .clearlist li:first-child a:before {
       content: ""; 
       display:none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header-level-1">
            <!-- Login -->
                <ul class="clearlist">
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

maybe better with some style to the `:before` element

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot to change css for the li element.. now it works.. and you can change the style to the :before element

Answer (score 0):

You have to select `<li>` instead of `<a>` in your code and your `.clearlist` class instead of your `.header-level-1` class.

Replace your CSS with this code, then it should work:

```
.clearlist li a:before {
 content: "|";
}

.clearlist li:first-child a:before {
 content: "";
}
```